# Managing data in docker volumes

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am having concerns about the difficulties that may arise when I want to move my dockerised application to a different host machine. Will I lose my data? How simple is it to migrate a volume? Is it as simple as creating a data dump or is it more involved? What other concerns may there be when storing data in docker volumes?

Comment: If you'd just focus on how to move data between containers, that would be a reasonable question. As is, this is too broad. We can answer technical details like the moving of data based on which you can draw your own conclusions about pros and cons.

Comment: @deceze I've limited the scope of the question.

Comment: I've limited it even more…

Comment: What kind of data? which platform you are on? How often you are moving data?

Comment: @Ntwobike, It's more an exploratory question. It's a mongodb. Currently the app would live on an on-site server, but there may be the need to move the app to a different host, which would ideally include the data. Data would not need to be moved often.